# Can Flurry Analytics report the user's location by city on Android?

Tags: android, geolocation, gps, location, flurry

**Question: can Flurry Analytics report the user's location by city (or more detailed region) on Android?**

I am wondering if anyone has any successful experience in reporting location data through the Flurry Analytics service for Android.

I am writing a healthcare app that will use location to provide access to local guidelines, and hence my users will feel justified in revealing their location.

I have carefully followed the API instructions here:
http://support.flurry.com/index.php?title=Analytics/GettingStarted/Android

and have experimented with both fine and coarse location permissions:

```
android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"
android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"
```

Despite this, the GeoLocation section of Flurry only reveals country location of use:

```
United Kingdom          127          100.0% 
Vatican City            0            0.0% 
Ukraine                 0            0.0% 
Switzerland             0            0.0% 
...
etc
```

Prior to adding the above permissions, the "Detailed Location" section was unavailable. After adding either one of the above permissions the "Detailed Location" section became available; but **all** city fields show "0; 0.0%":

```
York                    0            0.0% 
Wolverhampton           0            0.0% 
West Bromwich           0            0.0% 
Walsall                 0            0.0% 
...
etc
```

I have tested on the emulator, Samsung Galaxy S and HTC Wildfire handsets and I would be very interested to hear if others have had success in reporting city data, or if this is a limitation of the Flurry Analytics API?

Best wishes

Steven

Comment: Well you didn't actually type "android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"

Comment: Ah yes, well I did, I just didn't transcribe correctly. Thank you for point out the mistake and I have edited the question just now. Have you been able to get City location reporting working?

Answer (score 0):

Right, since this has popped up a few more times I've looked into it again and have found the (a?) solution!

It is possible to record user location as long as you use a real device, WITH a sim card OR wifi location enabled in settings.

I had wrongly assumed that fine location could be accessed by a device (in my case Samsung Galaxy S) without a sim card - after all GPS receivers do just that, but it seems that this was not so.

Sticking in a sim card or enabling wifi location did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to report user's location upto city level by configuring either of the following permissions in AndroidManifest.xml:
android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION or
android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
In case you are not able to set it, I recommend you to send across a mail to Flurry Support (support@flurry.com) with details of your implementation. 
(Disclaimer: I work in the Support team at Flurry)